# Infinite drawing view in android studio

Tags: android, canvas, view, scroll, infinite-scroll

I can make use of canvas and custom view to draw based on the input touch.. What I am unable to figure out is how to make the view scroll on double tap of the screen and scroll.  Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do scrolling on your own, you can use a **Scroller** and a **VelocityTracker** while overriding the **onTouchEvent** method of your custom view. To help you implement it I recommend looking through the Javadocs of these classes and taking a look at android widgets implementations that do scrolling like the [NumberPicker](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java).